# Does it worth keeping using the 'slots' mark in Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I understand very well the benefits and drawbacks of using the [new syntax for connecting slots in Qt 5](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). Just to mention some:

Pros:

- Compile time checks (the slots exists, compatible arguments...)
- Possibility to use lambdas (useful for very short and specific slots)
- Protecting private/protected slots from being called from outside the class ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17011414/1485885))

Contras:

- More complicate syntax in certain cases (specially overloads)
- No support for slots with arguments with a default value

I also know that there are some (very few) cases where it is not possible (yet) to use the new syntax ([`QFileDialog::open`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#open)).

Now, for the old syntax we had to mark those methods as `slots` in their definition, to mark the class with the `Q_OBJECT` macro, to *moc* it, and to inherit from `QObject`. As mentioned above, the new syntax doesn't require the methods to me marked as *slots*.

Is there any advantage of keeping the `slots` specifier when using (and only using) the new syntax? If the slots are the only `QMetaObject`'s featured used by a class, we could then avoid the necessity to mark the class as `Q_OBJECT`, or even to inherit from `QObject` itself.

Comment: If you're using QML, a function defined as a `slot` also becomes invokable from QML. But this can also be achieved by using `Q_INVOKABLE`.

Comment: @JarMan good point, I haven't used QML a lot yet so it is an unexplored world for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the slots are the only QMetaObject's featured used by a class, we could then avoid the necessity to mark the class as Q_OBJECT, or even to inherit from QObject itself.

You still need to inherit from `QObject` itself because you need an object to invoke the function on. That object must inherit from `QObject` so that Qt can detect which thread it is on (slot invocation may need to queued on a different thread) and to handle automatic disconnection when the receiver is destroyed.

However, you can work around this without too much trouble by passing the signalling `QObject` as the receiving object and using a lambda:

```
connect(qObjectInstance, &QObjectClass::signal, qObjectInstance, [&](){
    notAQObject->slot();
});
```

But you will have to manage the disconnection yourself if `notAQObject` could be destroyed before the signalling `QObject`.

As far as the `slots` macro: if you are using strictly C++ and are not looking up slots  through `QMetaObject`, `slots` doesn't do anything for you. `slots` or something similar (Q_INVOKABLE) is often necessary if you are inter-operating with something that uses the Qt MetaObject system more (such as QML).