# How to send data to tty0tty null modem emulator port opened in QT

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, virtual, tty

I have open working connection to a emulated serial port created with tty0tty nullmodem emulator via QSerialPort and I can write data to it like:

```
QSerialPort serial_stream;
...
serial_stream.setPortName(QString("/dev/tnt0"));
bool loc = serial_stream.open(serial_stream.ReadWrite)
...
serial_stream.write(buf);
```

I open a terminal and make a connection to the connected (in this case tnt1) tnt-port (e.g. tnt0 <-> tnt1 are connected) via "screen":

```
screen /dev/tnt1
```

When I execute the program I get the expected input (here "buf") on the screen. But how can I send data the way back to the opened port in Qt so that I can do the following to read data:

```
int size = serial_stream.bytesAvailable();
QByteArray data = serial_stream.read(size);
```

I already tried to stop the program with "sleep"...:

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
usleep(15*1000000);
```

...and send the data to it like this:

```
echo “TEXT“ > /dev/tnt1
```

But it does not work. I am glad for your help!

Comment: Try to use the dataTerminalReady signal. Connect the signal to a slot where you will read the serialport.

Comment: @Ibarros And how can I do that ?

Comment: In the mainwindow create a slot to read the serial port and connect the signal dataTerminalReady signal to that slot: connect(serialport,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readPortSlot()));

Comment: Actually is the readyRead() signal, but before that make sure the two ports have same configuration, like baudrate, parity bit....

Comment: I tried it out with readyRead(), but it did not work, `serial_stream.bytesAvailable()` is still 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Sending/Reading data with [*QSerialPort*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) using [*tty0tty* - null modem emulator (v1.2)](https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty)

### 1. Build up the *tty0tty*-connections:

In two ways it is possible to build up a *tty0tty*-connection (between two virtual ports). Both ways may require the [*kernel header files*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47330/what-exactly-are-linux-kernel-headers). For the 2. it is definitively necessary otherwise an [error while *make*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268363/make-stops-during-installation-of-tty0tty-null-modem-emulator) is inevitable.

**(1.) The short way:**

1. Download and extract *tty0tty* (first link in title).
2. Open a terminal and `cd` to `[Path to tty0tty-folder]/tty0tty/pts`
3. Execute `sudo ./tty0tty`

Then the two connected [pseudo terminal slaves](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21280/difference-between-pts-and-tty) should be shown:

> `(/dev/pts/X) <=> (/dev/pts/Y)` with X, Y variable.

**(2.) the longer way (but more or less permanent):**

1. Follow this [Installation guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/588806)

Maybe the *persisting across boots* does not work so it is necessary to repeat the following parts of the **Installation guide** after reboot:

5. Load the module

   - `sudo depmod`
   - `sudo modprobe tty0tty`
6. Give appropriate permissions to the new serial ports ([native terminal devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21280/difference-between-pts-and-tty))

   - `sudo chmod 666 /dev/tnt*`

After execute `ls /dev/tnt*` a list of ports shoud be shown:

> `/dev/tnt0 ... /dev/tnt7`

### 2. Test if the *tty0tty*-connection works (optional):

The connection can be tested with [*cat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29):

1. Open a terminal[1] and let show the output of one *pseudo/native terminal device*:

   - (1.)`cat /dev/pts/X` or (2.)`cat /dev/tnt0`
2. Open another terminal[2] and write to this *pseudo/native terminal device*:

   - (1.)`echo "message" > /dev/pts/Y` or (2.)`echo "hello" > /dev/tnt1`

The output should be shown in terminal[1]:

> `message`

**Additional info**: To stop *cat* press: **Ctrl** + **Z**

### 3. Open the terminal devices as ports with *QSerialPort* in a *Qt*-Project:

1. Add the *serialport*-reference to the [Qt-specific configuration options](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html) in the `[projectname].pro`-file:

   > `QT += serialport`

   **Additional info**: It is allowed to put all references in one line:

   > i.e. `QT+= core gui serialport ...`
2. Add required [header file](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/) in the desired `[name].h`-file:

   > `#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>`
3. Add two *QSerialPort*-objects, set the path of the *terminal devices* via [`void QSerialPort::setPortName(const QString &name)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#setPortName) and open the ports via [`bool QSerialPort::open(OpenMode mode)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#open) with desired permissions (`ReadOnly`, `WriteOnly`, `ReadWrite`). Example:

   ```
       std::string tty0ttyPort1 = "/dev/tnt0";// or = "/dev/pts/X
       std::string tty0ttyPort2 = "/dev/tnt1";// or = "/dev/pts/Y
       QSerialPort qport1;
       QSerialPort qport2;
       qport1.setPortName(QString(tty0ttyPort1.c_str()));
       bool isOpen1 = qport1.open(qport1.ReadWrite);//Read and Write permission
       std::cout << "isOpen1: " << isOpen1 << std::endl;
       qport2.setPortName(QString(tty0ttyPort2.c_str()));
       bool isOpen2 = qport2.open(qport2.ReadWrite);
       std::cout << "isOpen2: " << isOpen2 << std::endl;
   ```

`isOpen1` and `isOpen2` should be `true`:

> `isOpen1: 1`
>     `isOpen2: 1`

**Additional info 1**: Maybe is it required to execute the compiled code with super user permission:

1. Compile the Code.
2. Open a terminal and `cd` to `[Path to compiled project folder]/[projectname]`
3. Execute `sudo [executable_file]` or run as super user `su` [(inadvisable)](https://superuser.com/questions/218379/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root)

**Additional info 2**: If the following warning appears...:

> `QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread`

...there is no *Qt event loop* which should allways be in the `main()`-function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    //My Testcode (Showed above in section 3.3)
    return a.exec();
}
```

### 4. Using the opened *QSerialPort*s:

**(1.) Without Signals:**

Use [`qint64 QIODevice::write(const char * data)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#write-2) to write from one *QSerialPort* to another. Use [`qint64 QIODevice::read(char * data, qint64 maxSize)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#read) or [`QByteArray QIODevice::readAll()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readAll) to read the sended data. Here it is import to know that it is necessary to use [`bool QIODevice::waitForReadyRead(int msecs)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#waitForReadyRead) after sending the data via `QIODevice::write()` otherwise it will not work. I recommend also to use [`bool QIODevice::waitForBytesWritten(int msecs)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#waitForBytesWritten). Example:

```
    const char* sendMessage = "myMessage";
    std::cout << "sendMessage: " << sendMessage << std::endl;
    qport1.write(sendMessage);
    qport1.waitForBytesWritten(2000);
    qport2.waitForReadyRead(2000);//required
    const char* readMessage = qport2.readAll().data();
    std::cout << "readMessage: " << readMessage << std::endl;
```

Should give the output:

> `readMessage: myMessage`

If it is desired to read a defined number of bytes use `QIODevice::read()`:

```
    const char* readMessage = qport2.read(5);
    std::cout << "readMessage: " << readMessage << std::endl;
```

Should give the output:

> `readMessage: myMess`

**Additional info**: To check how many bytes are available to read use [`qint64 QIODevice::bytesAvailable() const`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#bytesAvailable). Example:

```
std::cout << qport2.bytesAvailable() << std::endl;
```

**(2.) With Signals:**

In the constructor of a Class it is possible to connect a [private slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147636/qt-private-slots-what-is-this) to the [`readyRead()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal using [`QObject::connect()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect):

```
Classname::Classname(){
    ...
    QObject::connect(&qport1, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(myPrivateSlotFunction()));
    //with "qport1" as sender and "this" as receiver
}

...

Classname::myPrivateSlotFunction(){
    ...
    const char* readMessage = qport1.readAll().data();
    ...
}
```